# Text using Cambria Math font in Windows forms gets shifted vertically

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cambria Math big top and bottom margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624229/cambria-math-big-top-and-bottom-margin)

I tried to draw the text (with font "Cambria Math") at position 0,0 of Windows form. but it shifted vertically down to some position.
Is there a way to draw it correctly at position 0,0?

```
        ![enter image description here][1]string st = ((char)4574).ToString();
        Font f = new System.Drawing.Font("Cambria Math", 12f);
        Graphics gr = this.CreateGraphics();
        gr.DrawString(st, f, Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 0));
```

Comment: I did not understand much on these link. Is there a way to fix?

Comment: By the sound of it, no. :( The font uses some OpenType extensions to do the maths stuff, and WinForms doesn't understand it so renders it oddly.

Comment: @Rawling : does this works fine with WPF?

Comment: It might well do. I wouldn't be surprised if WPF handles odd fonts better than WinForms does. I don't know much about it, though.